# how to display this code in json format using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
function data(name, age) {
  var biodata = {
    name: "meme ",
    age: "17",
    address: "Malang",
    hobbies: ["reading, hearing podcast"],
    is_married: false,
    list_school: [{
        name: "SMKN 5 Malang",
        year_in: 2016,
        year_out: 2018,
        major: "Rekayasa Perangkat Lunak"
      },
      {
        name: "SMKN 5 Malang",
        year_in: 2016,
        year_out: 2018,
        major: "Teknik Komputer Jaringan"
      }
    ],
    skill: [{
        name: "Programming",
        level: "Beginner"
      },
      {
        name: "Gaming",
        level: "Advanced"
      },
      {
        name: "Driving",
        level: "Advanced"
      },
    ],
    interest_in_coding: false
  };
  final = JSON.parse(nama + age + address + hobbies + is_married + list_school + skill + interest_in_coding)

}
return final
```

Comment: Your `data` function **does not** `return` anything... why did you not return the result?

Comment: Probably what you're looking for is `let final = JSON.stringify(biodata)`. The return statement should be inside the function, not after it.

Comment: how to do that ?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(object)` will show as json in UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, **[`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** is what you're looking for. You only have to stringify the whole object (in your case `biodata`).

> To learn more about JSON take a look at [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).

Furthermore your `return` was outside the function, which will throw an error.

```js
function data(name, age) {
  var biodata = {
    name: "meme ",
    age: "17",
    address: "Malang",
    hobbies: ["reading, hearing podcast"],
    is_married: false,
    list_school: [{
        name: "SMKN 5 Malang",
        year_in: 2016,
        year_out: 2018,
        major: "Rekayasa Perangkat Lunak"
      },
      {
        name: "SMKN 5 Malang",
        year_in: 2016,
        year_out: 2018,
        major: "Teknik Komputer Jaringan"
      }
    ],
    skill: [{
        name: "Programming",
        level: "Beginner"
      },
      {
        name: "Gaming",
        level: "Advanced"
      },
      {
        name: "Driving",
        level: "Advanced"
      },
    ],
    interest_in_coding: false
  };
  let final = JSON.stringify(biodata);
  return final;
}

console.log(data());
```

> If i get the right point you want to return and save the JSON into a
>   file? Take a look at **[this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0mtog7ab/)**.

*(If so, your question was not clear enough.)*

Comment: https://api.bukalapak.com/v2/products/f3vi.json - example json , how to make the code look like the link I gave

Comment: isnt it? i think so... The only difference is, that your "example json" stores more data. Click on "Run code snipped" to see the result.

Answer (score -1):

Perfect solution for your desire output 
Function I have used in this is

```
JSON.stringify(obj, replacer, space)
```

Please check JavaScript code highly focus on this code

> JSON.stringify(biodata, undefined, 4);

```js
function data(name,age) {
var el_down = document.getElementById("DOWN"); 
  var biodata = {
    name: "meme ",
    age: "17",
    address: "Malang",
    hobbies: ["reading, hearing podcast"],
    is_married: false,
    list_school: [{
        name: "SMKN 5 Malang",
        year_in: 2016,
        year_out: 2018,
        major: "Rekayasa Perangkat Lunak"
      },
      {
        name: "SMKN 5 Malang",
        year_in: 2016,
        year_out: 2018,
        major: "Teknik Komputer Jaringan"
      }
    ],
    skill: [{
        name: "Programming",
        level: "Beginner"
      },
      {
        name: "Gaming",
        level: "Advanced"
      },
      {
        name: "Driving",
        level: "Advanced"
      },
    ],
    interest_in_coding: false
  };
  
el_down.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(biodata, undefined, 4); 

}
data("name","age")
```

```html
<pre id="DOWN" style= "color:green; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;"> </pre>
```

Comment: the code above is almost right, it's just that the contents must be issued with "return" in json format, and may not use the file ".HTML"

Comment: @kuibeatbox this code here does nearly the same as in my answer, its only rendering the JSON into HTML. If i get you right, you want to get your return into a JSON-File? Take a look at my updated answer (below the code is a link to a fiddle).